# Cannot load file in VB.NET from root directory

Tags: .net, vb.net

I just made my first .net website.
I'm trying to use the following line of code to load a file from the current directory ( same diredtory all the web files are in).  I get a error saying file does not exist

```
  InstallFormTemp = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("installerform.html")
```

I copied the file to my c drive and chnage the line to

```
 InstallFormTemp = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("c:\installerform.html")
```

it worked, but now my site has to run a godaddy's webserver, so I cannot save stuff in the c drive, just my web directory.

How can I get  `My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText` to read files from the websites current directory????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, one of which is

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "installerform.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods which can help you out here - MapPath() and/or PhysicalPath() should be useful in this situation. This page provides an overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much for the link. its alwys nice to understand what we are doing imnstad of jjst cut and paste!